# How to add timeout to $.post in Jquery 3.x

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.post("result.php", {
    name: vname,
    email: vemail
}, function(response, status){ 
    // Required Callback Function
});
```

I hav this code, and I just want to add a timeout of 10 seconds, should the user network is down I should alert "check ur internet connections". I do not want to use $.ajax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a full `$.ajax()` call and provide the `timeout` property:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'result.php',
    timeout: 10000,
    data: {
        name: vname,
        email: vemail
    },
    success: function(response) { 
        // Required Callback Function
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can use `$.ajaxSetup()` to affect all AJAX calls in the current scope:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 10000
});
$.post("result.php", { name: vname, email: vemail }, function(response, status) { 
    // Required Callback Function
});
```

Comment: thanks, the universal ajaxSetup way was what I was looking for.